# ¿Cómo usar la funcion str en R?

Tags: r

podrían darme un ejemplo de como usando la función str en Rstudio se puede verificar que por ejemplo: la columna de "animales" es de tipo carácter

Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con el siguiente data frame:

```
datos = data.frame(animales = c("Conejo","Perro","Raton"),
                   peso = c(2,10,0.1),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
> datos
  animales peso
1   Conejo  2.0
2    Perro 10.0
3    Raton  0.1
```

Se puede consultar la estructura de la columna animales con `str`

```
> str(datos$animales)
 chr [1:3] "Conejo" "Perro" "Raton"
```

Las primeras tres letras indican que tipo de datos hay en esa columna. En este caso `chr` indica que contiene cadenas de caracteres.

Otra forma es utilizando la funcion `typeof`:

```
> typeof(datos$animales)
[1] "character"
```

Que podria ser utilizada para verificar el tipo de datos:

```
> typeof(datos$animales)=="character"
[1] TRUE
> typeof(datos$peso)=="character"
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Y si se quiere usar la salida de `str` se puede también hacer esto `s <- capture.output(str(datos$animales))`y luego `if (grep(' chr ', s) >0 ) {print("Es un String")}`

Comment: Gracias a ambos, es exactamente lo que quería saber

Comment: Una duda más, es independiente, por ejemplo, si entre **datos = data.frame**  el signo  **=** es reemplazado por el signo **<-**, es decir: **datos <- data.frame**?

Comment: `<-` y `=` cumplen la misma funcion: asignan el objeto de la derecha en la variable de la izquierda.  Tambien existe `->` que asigna lo de la izquierda a la variable de la derecha.  Yo prefiero el `=` porque tambien se usa asi en otros lenguajes.

Comment: Cierto lo que se comenta (son exactamente iguales). Lo habitual es ver "<-" para los procesos de asignación y "=" para definir argumentos en una función.